# Hokuyo Laser Scanner not working in Gazebo using ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, gazebo, hokuyo-laser, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the Hokuyo Laser scanner on my mobile robot using ROS Kinetic and it does NOT detect any object in it's field of vision.

I added the following code snippet in my .xacro file

```
<joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="fixed">
<axis xyz="0 1 0" />
<origin xyz=".15 0 .1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<parent link="chassis"/>
<child link="hokuyo"/>
</joint>

<!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
<link name="hokuyo">
<collision>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <geometry>
<box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
  </geometry>
</collision>

<visual>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <geometry>
    <mesh filename="package://mybot_description/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
  </geometry>
</visual>

<inertial>
  <mass value="1e-5" />
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
</inertial>
</link>
```

and the following code snippet in my .gazebo file.

```
<!-- hokuyo -->
  <gazebo reference="hokuyo">
    <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>40</update_rate>
   <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.10</min>
      <max>30.0</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <!-- Noise parameters based on published spec for Hokuyo laser
           achieving "+-30mm" accuracy at range < 10m.  A mean of 0.0m and
           stddev of 0.01m will put 99.7% of samples within 0.03m of the true
           reading. -->
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.01</stddev>
    </noise>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
    <topicName>/mybot/laser/scan</topicName>
    <frameName>hokuyo</frameName>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
</gazebo>
```

I have created a hokuyo.dae file as well. I will post that if needed, however the issue is that the laser scanner is not detecting any object in it's field of vision. Where is the problem?

The following [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6z1f3gdcxq4pzq/Laser%20Scanner%20Problem.png?dl=0) says it all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250556/hokuyo-laser-scanner-not-working-in-gazebo-using-ros-kinetic/) by [ClarkGrissom](https://answers.ros.org/users/28830/clarkgrissom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-06-02**:
`gpu_laser` only work for Nvidia card, see [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/224403/gazebo-laser-plug-in-fails-to-publish-scan-results-in-rviz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the using the non-GPU version of the laser. Change the line      to       and replace      with

---

Originally posted by [Dan.K](https://answers.ros.org/users/26460/dan.k/) with karma: 76 on 2017-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [utkuolcar](https://answers.ros.org/users/64419/utkuolcar/) on 2020-12-01**:
Thank you. Only this option worked for me.